# Move featured image metabox under title box?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible to move the featured image meta box under the title form for a custom post type?  I'm also looking to see if there is a programmatic way to "order" the meta boxes?  Thank you in advance for your time.

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_content_before_editor' );   function add_content_before_editor() { 
add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Custom Featured Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high'); 
  echo '<div class=\"postbox-container\">I'm above the content area!</div>'; 
  }
```

The code above IS working the text "I'm above the content area!" does show where I expected. But the add_meta_box does not.

Answer (score 1):

use this to move featured image:

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'customposttype_image_box');

function customposttype_image_box() {

    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'customposttype', 'side' );

    add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Custom Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'customposttype', 'normal', 'high');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You probably want to create a custom page template.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Bridget Arrington.  I should have been more clear and explained I was referring to the admin area.  I have been able to isolate the area with  'add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_content_before_editor' );
function add_content_before_editor() {

    add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('Custom Featured Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high');
    echo '<div class=\"postbox-container\"><h2>Move it here?  Can not move items above the editor. Trying to find a work around.</h2></div>';
}' the text will show as expcted but the metabox will not.

Comment: @PeterB, please, update your question with your code... The downvote you received probably is because you did not ask a clear question, and this answer is proof of that... :/

Comment: That you @brasofilo for the advice, please let me know if that helps you answer my question.